# Having trouble with a simple C++ Game

Tags: c++

I am a begginer programmer and i am currently learning C++ as my fist ever language.I've been trying to make a simple game, but its just not working.Its not that is giving me an error its that when i start it up it does not do what it is supposed to do.(Using Code::Blocks)Also i know theres a lot of unused classes, functions, variables etc.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main();

//variables
const int X = 0;
const int Y = 10;
const int Z = 0;
int X1 = X;
int Y1 = Y;
int Z1 = Z;
int Input;
int Input2;

int Menu()
{
    cout<<"Please type what you want to do."<<endl;
    cin>>Input;

    return Input;
   //deciding what they want to do.
}

int Calculating()
{
  //Calculating Function(Unused)
}    

class Player
{
public:
    void Movement()
    {
        //the loop that activates when the Input == 1
       while(1)
    {
        cout<<"2 - Move"<<endl;
        do
        {
            cin>>Input2;
        }while(Input2 < 3 && Input2 > 1);

        switch(Input2)
        {
        case 1:
            cout<<"You moved"<<endl;
        }
    }
    }
    void Attack()
    {
       //the loop that activates when the Input == 2
      while(1)
    {
       cout<<"1 - Sword Dance"<<endl;
       do
       {
           cin>>Input2;
       }while(Input2 < 3 && Input2 > 1);

       switch(Input2)
       {
       case 1:
        cout<<"DMG"<<endl;
        break;
       }
    }
    }
};

class Enemy
{
 //Enemy class(Unused)
};   

int main()
{    
    Player Pl;
//if the chosen number was 1 it will make the Player move.
//if the chosen number was 2 it will make the Player attack.
      if(Input == 1)
   {
       Pl.Movement();
   }
   else if(Input == 2)
   {
       Pl.Attack();
   }

    Menu();
 //calling the Menu function
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to remove the unused classes, functions, and variables before posting. At best it's rude to make people who are trying to help you dig through this code.

Comment: *"it does not do what it is supposed to do"*. And what should it does, what it currently does ?

Answer (score 1):

in your Main you have to call `Menu()` as:

```
int main()
{

    Player Pl;
   Input=Menu();
    //if the chosen number was 1 it will make the Player move.
   //if the chosen number was 2 it will make the Player attack.
   if(Input == 1)
   {
       Pl.Movement();
   }
   else if(Input == 2)
   {
       Pl.Attack();
   }

   Menu();
  //calling the Menu function
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see you set Input up as a Global variable, but never initialised it.

So the flow of your Program is:

1. P1 gets created
2. The if-statement gets called, but the Input is not initialised yet. So its undefined. As far as i know its random and the possibility that its one or two is rather small.
3. Menu gets called and within Menu() Input gets set. But at this point its to late.
4. The Program ends.

My tip for you is to call Menu() right after the P1 gets created.